# It is possible to use child class to implement Separation of concerns using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, orm

My goal is async loading of related entities using DBContext.

Let imagine two projects. The first named `MyApp.Domain` and contains domain entities.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Domain
{
    public class PlanPage
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace MyApp.Domain
{
    public class PlanPageDay
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid PlanPageId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The second project named `MyApp.Infrastructure.EntityFramework` and contains configuration of projection entities to database. It also contains class which extends domain entity and implements Entity framework specific logic.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Models
{
    public class PlanPageEntity : PlanPage
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

        protected PlanPageEntity(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        }

        public ICollection<PlanPageDay>? Days { get; set; }

        public async Task<ICollection<PlanPageDay>> GetDays()
        {
            return Days ??= await _applicationDbContext.PlanPageDays
                .Where(pd => pd.PlanPageId == Id)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this example is simple. We separate infrastructure code from domain code. Look how do we plan to use this concept:

```cs
// Entity initializing code. Placing somewhere in domain logic.
var plan = new PlanPage(/*some constructor arguments*/);

// Entity loading code. Placing somewhere in infrastructure implementation.
public async Task<PlanPage> GetPlanPage(Guid id)
{
    return await _applicationDbContext.Set<PlanPageEntity>().FindAsync(id);
}
```

Note that we tell to Entity framework to use child class (`PlanPageEntity`) so it can handle all specific things that it can.

The question is: Is it possible to configure the EF so that it allows us to use this concept?

Comment: you should define the ef entities independent from the domain entities. Use a mapper to map between them but no inheritance.

Comment: This ruins subject concept. Goal is to provide loaders inside a domain. Mapper requires to construct new object separately from original.

Comment: I completely agree with Sir Rufo here: mixing models from your domain logic with data access models is a bad idea. Your headache will only get worse down the line and this smells of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. However, for me it is sad. This concept looked like a pretty good solution. In this case, I am forced to look for another way of implementation.

Comment: @Xerillio, could you post a reasoned refutation as an answer? I am not the only supporter of this idea and I would like to fix this issue for others who will seek a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested here's a little more details for my opinion stated in the comments.

---

The main reason why I think your current approach is a bad idea is that it violates the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle: when you are mixing domain models with data access models, you make your domain logic completely dependent on how you model the data in your database. This quickly limits your options because the database may have some restrictions on how you can model your data that doesn't fit well with the domain logic you want to implement as well as making maintenance difficult. E.g. if you decide to split up one DB table into two then you might have a big task ahead of you in order to make your domain logic work with those two new models/tables. Additionally, making performance optimizations in your database easily becomes a nightmare if not thought through ahead of time - and you shouldn't spend time thinking of optimizing your system before it's necessary.

I know this is a little abstract since I don't know much about your domain but I'm sure I could find more arguments against it.

---

Instead, separating data access models (and in general all external data models) from your domain models makes it much easier to maintain: if you need to make some changes to your database, you simply need to update the logic that maps the data from your data access models to your domain model - nothing in your domain logic needs to change.

In the examples you have given, you have already logically separated your domain models and data access models into two separate projects. So why not follow through with that thought and separate the two with a binding/mapping layer in-between?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure the EF so that it allows us to use this concept?

Yes.  Essentially you have DTO's, and your Entities derive from your DTOs.  So when you fetch an Entity you can return it directly.  But if you wouldn't be able to attach a non-Entity, so you'd have to map it.  It's going to be inconvenient, and like 99.999% of bespoke entity and repository designs, will be ultimately a waste of time.

This is somewhat similar to the what EF already does for you.  Start with persistence-ignorant Entity classes, and introduce persistence-aware runtime subtypes for scenarios that require them, which is basically just Lazy Loading.